# How to continue execution of "for" loop when assertion fails in Behave framework (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

```
@then("----------------------------------")
def step_impl(context, vnf):
        some_list=[] //  list of values
        is_log_exists = False 
        for log in context:
                for key, val in log.items(): 
                        is_log_exists = all(elem in val for elem in some_list) // checking if all the element in  some_list is present in val which is also a list.
        assert is_log_exists, f"Failed"
```

Refer the above piece of code. As soon as the assertion failed instead of stopping the execution, is there any other way to continue the next iteration in for loop? whenever assertion failure happens it should be seen in the console and next iteration should start.

Comment: Please review your text below the code because it's quite hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Madhuvanthi.

I think you should track the failures individually, and then create a custom assertion message to display errors to the user:

```
@then("----------------------------------")
def step_impl(context, vnf):
    some_list=[] #  list of values
    failures = list()
    for log in context:
        for key, val in log.items(): 
            for elem in some_list():
                if val not in elem:
                    failures.append((val, elem))

    # Create an assertion message detailing why the assertion failed
    assert_msg = "The following values were not found in the corresponding element:\n"
    for val, elem in failures:
        assert_msg += "Value: {}, Element: {}\n".format(val, elem)

    # This form of the assertion allows you to pass in a custom message that will be
    # displayed only if the assertion is False
    assert len(failures) == 0, assert_msg
```